# How to pad all strings in a comma separated set of strings

Tags: c#, jquery, string, split, padding

Is there a way to pad each individual string in a comma separated string in one shot?

I can split the comma separated string, go through each string and pad it (with 0, for 3 character) and join the array elements again but not sure if it can be done in one shot.

For instance, if I have:

```
var someString = "01,002,7";
```

how can I end up with "001,002,007"?

I can do this client side (jQuery) or server side (C#)

Comment: Split by comma, pad, join ... Where is the problem?

Comment: String manipulation is a javascript problem, not a jQuery problem.

Comment: Why all the down votes?

Comment: wow! 5 downvotes! Cloudy day everywhere?

Comment: @Selvin that was my first thought, I just thought there might be a more elegant way of doing it in one shot

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I mentioned in my post the way I would do it would be to to split, process and join. Nothing too complicated to include code. I was asking if there was a more elegant way of doing it, as many responders have posted.

Comment: Don't understand why this was closed. Says to be more "focused". How? It is a single question and clear. I have a comma-separated string of integers and want to be able to pad each integer within it. I also mentioned in the question how I would do it but looking for a better way to do it. It is quite evident from the number of answers, of which I chose one to use, that it is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this in Javascript you can split the string by `,` and use `map()` it build another array which pads the leading zeroes, like this:

```js
var someString = "01,002,7".split(',').map(v => v.padStart(3, '0')).join(',');
console.log(someString);
```

Note that this won't work in IE due to the use of arrow functions and `padStart()`. If you want a legacy browser safe version, use this:

```js
var someString = "01,002,7".split(',').map(function(v) {
  return ('000' + v).slice(-3)
}).join(',');
console.log(someString);
```

Answer (score 3):

Server side approach:

*Split/Join/Pad*

```
string someString = "01,002,7";
string result = string.Join(",", someString.Split(',').Select(x => x.PadLeft(3, '0')));
```

---

[Andreas'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59631794/1315444) `RegEx` *approach server side*

```
string someString = "01,002,7";
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(someString, @"\b\d{1,2}\b", m => m.Value.PadLeft(3, '0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you don't want to go with the obvious solution mentioned in your "question" but you could also use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var input = "01,002,7";
var output = input.replace(/\b\d{1,2}\b/g, m => m.padStart(3, "0"));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var s = "01,2,3";
var t = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.PadLeft(3, '0')).Aggregate((z,c)=>z+","+c);
Console.WriteLine(t);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thank you all, so many excellent responses. I will try both server and client side approaches and update, I am partial to client side manipulation. Now, if someone would tell me what caused so many down votes so next time I won't make the same mistake, that would be awesome (question format, nature of question, ...)